# Why datastax/nodejs-driver is slow?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

It takes 20 seconds to get a response for a simple select query using nodejs driver. But with cqlsh it takes less than one second.

Enabled the logging on the connection and it shows lot of connection events as below

```
SELECT * FROM developer WHERE username=?

2015-06-13T05:48:39.635Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:39.635Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:39.637Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:44.641Z log event: warning -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:44.641Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.646Z log event: warning -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.647Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.647Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.648Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.648Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.651Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.651Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.652Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.652Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.652Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.653Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.654Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.654Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.654Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.654Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.654Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.655Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.662Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.662Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.662Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.663Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.663Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.684Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.690Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.718Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.718Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.719Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.725Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.725Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.725Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.726Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.726Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.726Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.727Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:49.727Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:54.728Z log event: warning -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:54.729Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:59.734Z log event: warning -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:59.735Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:48:59.735Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T05:49:00.160Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"

result 1
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The [node.js driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#features) features node auto discovery. This indicates that the driver will become aware of other nodes participating in the cluster even though only a single contact point is supplied.

Looking at the log message in your original post we see some warning messages labeled `Connection`. While we don't have the full log messages here, we could guess that it attempted to try the two unavailable nodes before moving on to the third node which is accessible. Looking at the source code of the driver in [`connection.js`](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/bc4ad0dee07b414441a67881d49b9f8d26058d73/lib/connection.js#L181) we see a warning is emitted when there is an error connecting.

Furthermore in [`client-options.js`](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/bc4ad0dee07b414441a67881d49b9f8d26058d73/lib/client-options.js#L36) we see there is a timeout on connections of 5 seconds. This matches up with the timing between log messages in your output.

If the driver attempting to connect to each node is failing, then waiting for timeouts could account for your ~20 second query time. Make sure all nodes are individually accessible and you will see your performance increase.

Comment: Check out the docs for load balancing policies if you are interested in learning more about how nodes are selected for running a query.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.1/common/drivers/reference/tuningPolicies.html#retry-policy

Answer (score -1):

I was running a 3 node cluster using docker https://github.com/pokle/cassandra
and only one node was exposed to outside.

It works very fast when used a single node cluster.
I think the driver tries to connects other hosts in the cluster although I have put only one host in the contactPoints option.

The log now shows

```
SELECT * FROM developer WHERE username='xxx@xxxxx.xx'

2015-06-13T06:20:05.241Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.241Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.242Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.243Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.243Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.244Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.245Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.246Z log event: info -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.246Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.246Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.246Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.247Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.248Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.248Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.248Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.248Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.248Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.249Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.255Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.255Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.255Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.256Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.256Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.258Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.262Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.273Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.273Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.274Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.275Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.275Z log event: info -- "ControlConnection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.275Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.276Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.276Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.276Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.276Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.278Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.279Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"
2015-06-13T06:20:05.283Z log event: verbose -- "Connection"

result 1
```